# Flask/Stripe environment variable on windows error

Tags: python, windows-10, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup a project on Windows 10 and Flask but couldn't get Stripe variables set in Environment Variables. Stripe uses `os.environ` and that means it only can call the environment if it exists in Windows env variables. I added environment variables as:

```
Variable = secret_key
Value = mysecretkeysomething
```

My code is in .py is below:

```
import stripe

stripe_keys = {
    'secret_key': os.environ['mysecretkeysomething'],
    'publishable_key': os.environ['mysecretkeysomething']}

stripe.api_key = stripe_keys['secret_key']
```

I did this both for secret_key and publish key in environment variables. 
    Later on I tried to add this directly from command prompt using:

```
setx SECRET_KEY mysecretkeysomething

setx PUBLISHABLE_KEY mypublishablekeysomething
```

It showed command execution a success for both but still I get the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "app.py", line 13, in <module>
        'secret_key': os.environ['mysecretkeysomething'],
      File "C:\Users\Alikhan\flask_parliment\env\lib\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__
        return self.data[key.upper()]
    KeyError: 'MYSECRETKEYSOMETHING'
```

I even tried with setx using `STRIPE_SECRET_KEY` instead of `SECRET_KEY` and same for publish key. Also like `'secret_key'` in small letters. Every time I made changes from terminal I've restarted my terminal. I am testing in dev environment and with test keys. Help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get environment variables for Windows in your Flask configuration file with `os.getenv('key', 'default value')`.